# how to find the direction

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to find a direction for the collision with the wall, use Raycaster rays to determine the collision with walls for the player.
My player is controlled by buttons WASD, and change the direction of the axis of Y, I found an example for the collision http://webmaestro.fr/blog/basic-collisions-detection-with-three-js-raycaster/, but there is only the axis X and Z

```
/**player move**/
        if(kerk.controller.moveRight && this.moveX) this.player.translateX(  moveDistance2 );
        if(kerk.controller.moveLeft && this.moveX) this.player.translateX(  -moveDistance2 );
        if(kerk.controller.moveUp && this.moveZ) this.player.translateZ( -moveDistance );
        if(kerk.controller.moveBottom && this.moveZ) this.player.translateZ( moveDistance2 );

....

/**rotation player**/
this.player.rotation.y += mouse.x > scCenter ? -this.camRot : this.camRot;


....

this.rays = [
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1),
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1),
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, -1),
        new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1),
        new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, -1),
        new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0),
        new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 1)
];
this.caster = new THREE.Raycaster();

.....

for (i = 0; i < this.rays.length; i += 1) {
```

but the player has changed the direction of the axis of Y

how do I find the direction for each of the 8 sides of the Raycaster?

```
        this.caster.set(this.player.position, this.rays[i]);

        collisions = this.caster.intersectObjects(obstacles);

        if (collisions.length > 0 && collisions[0].distance <= distance) {

            if ((i === 0 || i === 1 || i === 7) && kerk.controller.moveUp === 1) {
                this.moveZ = 0;
            } else if ((i === 3 || i === 4 || i === 5) && kerk.controller.moveBottom === -1) {
                this.moveZ = 0;
            }
            if ((i === 1 || i === 2 || i === 3) && kerk.controller.moveRight === 1) {
                this.moveX = 0;
            } else if ((i === 5 || i === 6 || i === 7) && kerk.controller.moveLeft === -1) {
                this.moveX = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I just can not figure out how to find the direction to 8 sides when the player changes the direction of the axis of Y

Maybe this is the right example but it works for me in a strange way by 25%, maybe I dropped it, or that you need something to update the Raycaster

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but just in case a small math refresh:

To calculate the direction you need two points, (does not matter the number of dimensions), p1 and p2 for example. As a result a vector is created, v1, this is a vector, not a direction, to convert it as a direction you just need to normalize it.

In three.js you would do something like that:

```
var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1, z1);
var p2 = new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
var v = new THREE.Vector3();

v.subVectors(p2, p1);
v.normalize();
```